# How to Automate Build and Deployment in Visual Studio TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, automation

I am looking to automate Build and Deployment in Visual Studio T.F.S and going through this link for the same.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.ibm-websphere

It clearly says to install IBM Websphere Extension but i am not sure from where can i get it done?

Comment: What do you want to deploy? Which version of TFS are you using? Where do you want to deploy to?

Comment: @WouterdeKort I want to deploy my project in order to bring my application up after i commit my code changes. Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013 is the version that i am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the the old Xaml build system (TFS 2013 and earlier version), you can follow the steps mentioned in below link to build and deploy the project:
[Automated Web Deployment and Team Build Using TFS 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/automated-web-deployment-and-team-build-using-tfs-2013/)

If you are using vNext build (TFS 2015 and later version), you can use the CI/CD. Please see [Continuous integration, test, and deployment tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/example-continuous-testing) and [CI/CD Hello world](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#a-quick-introduction-to-cicd) for details.

Comment: where can this TFS version be checked?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need websphere in order to automate builds, builds are created by a build server and placed in an output ( drop folder location ).

Deployment can be handed by creating post build scripts, there are a number of solutions for handling larger deployments but start with the basic build deployment workflow and scale from there.

See the following QuickStart to get an idea of build/deployment process.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#create-a-release-definition

Comment: Hi Sir, your answer looks valid for VSTS. Can the same thing be done with TFS too?

Comment: @chirag garg It's based on your TFS version, If you are using the the old Xaml  build system (TFS 2013 and earlier version), then it's not available. If you are using vNext build (TFS 2015 and later version), then it's valid.